# distribute a value starting from the first months

Tags: sql, firebird

1. let be a query such as the following.

Select MONTH, sum(RECEIVABLES), sum(COLLECTED) from TABLE1 group by MONTH

```
result 

    MONTH      RECEIVABLES   COLLECTED
    JANUARY         2             0
    FEBRUARY        1             0
    MARCH           3             0
```

2. Now, APRIL 4 get made COLLECTED ...

Question: APRIL 4 in value, starting from the first month , we distribute according to how COLLECTED column.

as follows

```
    MONTH    RECEIVABLES  COLLECTED
    JANUARY         2        2
    FEBRUARY        1        1
    MARCH           3        1
    APRIL           0        0
```

With SQL or stored procedures...
thanks...

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want or how this "DISTIRIBUTE" should be calculated.

Comment: With Firebird 2.5 and earlier you'd probably need to do this with a stored procedure, with the upcoming Firebird 3 (which has WINDOW functions), you might be able to do to it in a query; not sure.